# SQL Server: How to find and replace multiple quote with single quote in table data

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, sql-update

By mistake in my table, multiple quotes have been stored. suppose some time two double-quote stored in item name like `Alzheimer''s Disease (AD)` or `Alzheimer'''s Disease (AD)` or `Alzheimer'''''''''s Disease (AD)`.

Now I want to execute a SQL query which will find more than one single quote in `itemname` column and replaces those multiple quotes with a single quote.

This way I can update double quote with a single quote

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET ItemName = REPLACE(ItemName, '''', ''')
```

I assume the above statement will not do what I am trying to do.

I want to find and replace multiple quotes with a single quote.

If there are two quotes or 8 quotes or 5 quote means multiple quotes. More than one quote will be replaced with a single quote in the item name column. so please tell me what query does this job nicely.

I already mention though that no of the quote is unknown in my case which is stored in the item name column of table.

So how to detect which data has to quote more than one and update accordingly?

Please suggest some code example. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach: using nested `replace()` calls:

```
replace(replace(replace(mycol, '''', '+-'), '-+', ''), '+-', '''')
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=91c887f087eaaab0147a8c452721dd95)**:

```
select mycol, replace(replace(replace(mycol, '''', '+-'), '-+', ''), '+-', '''') mycol_new
from (values 
    ('Alzheimer''s Disease (AD)'), 
    ('Alzheimer''''s Disease (AD)'), 
    ('Alzheimer''''''''''s Disease (AD)')
) t(mycol)
```

```
mycol                        | mycol_new               
:--------------------------- | :-----------------------
Alzheimer's Disease (AD)     | Alzheimer's Disease (AD)
Alzheimer''s Disease (AD)    | Alzheimer's Disease (AD)
Alzheimer'''''s Disease (AD) | Alzheimer's Disease (AD)
```

Comment: i do not know how many quotes are there ? so i need a logic which will find out those records where quote found more than one and there sql replace all quotes with single quotes.

Comment: what is these characters used for '+-' or '-+' ? not clear how it works !!

Comment: @KendoStarter: this does work for a variable number of quotes, as you can see in the demo. `+-` and `-+` are just two pairs of random characters that are mirrored one to the other. This could as well be `'%*` and `*%`, or `{}` and `}{`.

Comment: sorry i do not understand the usage of +- and -+ characters. help me to understand their usage. what these char does in update?

Comment: i have checked your fiddle and it is working but it is working and what is their underlying logic not clear. i gave u a up vote. thanks

Comment: @KendoStarter: the logic is to use the pairs or "mirror" strings to remove pairs of single quotes. This is more efficient that running multiple update queries, as show in the accepted answer (a single query gets the job done, regardless of how many single quotes need to be removed).

Comment: @KendoStarter Take GMB's code and replace the _select list_ with `mycol, replace(mycol, '''', '+-') Step1, replace(replace(mycol, '''', '+-'), '-+', '') Step2, replace(replace(replace(mycol, '''', '+-'), '-+', ''), '+-', '''') mycol_new` to see the intermediate steps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to double you single quotes in your `UPDATE` statement.  But besides that your statement should work.
If you have a combination of more than 2 quotes, you can execute the statement multiple times, e.g. in a WHILE loop:

```
WHILE (@@ROWCOUNT >0)
BEGIN
    UPDATE MyTable 
    SET ItemName=REPLACE(ItemName,'''''','''')
    WHERE ItemName LIKE '%''''%'
END
```

Comment: i will check and let you know after few hour because i am not before sql server pc. thanks for the answer.